# Ubuntu Core 20 arm64 Raspberry Pi 4 4Gb "start4.elf not compatible"

Tags: boot, system-installation, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I have installed Ubuntu Core on my SD card and run it on a RPi 4 4GB of my school when I didn't have mine and I could run the installation procedure and boot the os with no issue.

But when I have tried the same SD card on my own one, it boots with this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWYVp.jpg)

I have also tried with a freshly downloaded image, and it showed the same screen.
I have planned to use it as a companion computer with a Pixhawk autopilote and Ubuntu Core kind of seduce me for the use i have planned for it.

Is someone have a solution for it? Is it due to my bootloader version?
I'll try the desktop version of Ubuntu in the meantime

Edit 11/04/2022: Ubuntu desktop from raspberry pi imager work but freeze when I try to run a command on the terminal

Comment: The last two lines of your output: "This board requires newer software" and the URL to get it from.

Comment: I'have check the web page but its for dowloading raspberry pi os which I don't want use.
I'have also tried ubuntu desktop it work, but the one i need is Ubuntu Core

Comment: Is there a reason you want Core which is snaps only instead of Ubuntu Server which is snaps and apt powered?  I believe Core is in the RPi imager as well, though it might be running on older items than standard ubuntu server

Comment: I'have just read Ubuntu core was good for embbeded related application on the paper. So I just wanted to at least try it to build my opinion about it

Comment: It seems that it is due to the rev of my board which is C03115, I guess I'll need to wait Canonical updating core or try this trick following this issue [link](https://community.volumio.org/t/volumio-not-working-on-raspberry-pi-4-rev-1-5-board-start4-elf-not-compatible/53113).
Am I right ?

Comment: I think you are right re: Canonical needing to update Core with the new boards. I have a new RPi 4 and am receiving the same error.